# Jenkins : Copy artifacts from one agent to another from last stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am using more than one agents in my declarative pipeline. Is there anyway to copy artifacts (input.txt) from agent1 to agent2? here is my declarative pipeline,

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                label 'agent1'
            }

            steps {
                sh 'echo arjun > input.txt'

            }
            post {
                always {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'input.txt',
                            fingerprint: true
                }
            }

        }
        stage('Test') {
            agent {
                label 'agent2'
            }

            steps {
                sh 'cat input.txt'
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One way to copy files is using the `stash` and `unstash` directive in Jenkins. However, keep in mind that it is useful for only small files. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build

Comment: Let me know, if it worked for you or not. I will update the answer after that.

Comment: i need to copy big files and directories. is there any way to do that?

Comment: one more disadvantage of using stash -unstash is, unstash will not work if my job is failed and i am trying to restart the same. it will fail with error "No such saved stash". please suggest some work around.

Comment: I agree. Have you checked the plugin [Publish over SSH](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) that can do exactly that.

Given your Jenkinsfile, it then turns into this:

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent { label 'agent1' }
            steps {
                sh 'echo arjun > input.txt'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'input.txt', fingerprint: true
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            agent { label 'agent2' }
            steps {
                // this brings artifacts from job named as this one, and this build
                step([
                    $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                    filter: 'input.txt',
                    fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                    optional: true,
                    projectName: env.JOB_NAME,
                    selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector',
                            buildNumber: env.BUILD_NUMBER]
                ])

                sh 'cat input.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its failed with below error ```GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: repo-name/main
This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: do you have any solution ?

Comment: above given solution is working is i am giving permission to that branch, but i am using multibranch pipeline, how it will work for that. ```options {
        copyArtifactPermission('main');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use stash and unstash.

example from:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/

```
// First we'll generate a text file in a subdirectory on one node and stash it.
stage "first step on first node"

// Run on a node with the "first-node" label.
node('first-node') {
    // Make the output directory.
    sh "mkdir -p output"

    // Write a text file there.
    writeFile file: "output/somefile", text: "Hey look, some text."

    // Stash that directory and file.
    // Note that the includes could be "output/", "output/*" as below, or even
    // "output/**/*" - it all works out basically the same.
    stash name: "first-stash", includes: "output/*"
}

// Next, we'll make a new directory on a second node, and unstash the original
// into that new directory, rather than into the root of the build.
stage "second step on second node"

// Run on a node with the "second-node" label.
node('second-node') {
    // Run the unstash from within that directory!
    dir("first-stash") {
        unstash "first-stash"
    }

    // Look, no output directory under the root!
    // pwd() outputs the current directory Pipeline is running in.
    sh "ls -la ${pwd()}"

    // And look, output directory is there under first-stash!
    sh "ls -la ${pwd()}/first-stash"
}
```